# Exercism RNA Transcription Failing

Tags: javascript

For some reason, I'm having issues with this exercise. I've tried various iterations of this, but it's still failing on this test:

```js
xtest('correctly handles invalid input', () => {
    expect(() => toRna('U')).toThrow(new Error('Invalid input DNA.'));
});
```

Here's my code. If anyone can spot the problem, I'd be eternally grateful.

```js
const toRna = function(dna) {
  const parseDna = dna.split("");
  let rna = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < parseDna.length; i++) {
    if (parseDna[i] === "G") {
      rna += "C";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "C") {
      rna += "G";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "T") {
      rna += "A";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "A") {
      rna += "U";
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid input DNA.");
    // This part doesn't work for some reason.
    }
  }
  return rna;
};

console.log(toRna("ACGT"));
```

Here is the test class it's running:

```js
import { toRna } from './rna-transcription';

describe('Transcriptor', () => {
  test('correctly handles invalid input', () => {
    expect(() => toRna('U')).toThrow(new Error('Invalid input DNA.'));
  });

  test('correctly handles completely invalid input', () => {
    expect(() => toRna('XXX')).toThrow(new Error('Invalid input DNA.'));
  });

  test('correctly handles partially invalid input', () => {
    expect(() => toRna('ACGTXXXCTTAA')).toThrow(new Error('Invalid input DNA.'));
  });
});
```

Comment: besides that, you could significantly simplify your code with a regular expression which match valid input, then `replace()` letters to convert toRna (or create matching arrays) to avoid all your tests

Comment: what are you working on? looks very cool. any chance it is on github?

Comment: It's a site called exercism.io. 
You sign up for a path (in this case javascript), and you download lessons via the command line after you install their CLI: https://exercism.io/cli-walkthrough

Comment: I should add, there's zero hand-holding involved. If you can't figure it out, you can submit a partially completed solution back and then look through a list of other's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine.

When you run console.log(toRna("U")) , you do indeed get an error thrown!

```
Error: Invalid input DNA.
    at toRna (/home/ashvitha/Desktop/dna.js:14:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ashvitha/Desktop/dna.js:21:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

What's going wrong is your expect seems to be failing. Not sure if this is an assignment, but you should look into that part of your code to see where it's going wrong!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the assignments in Exercism. Like you said, everything seems to be working as expected, but it fails the tests on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `export` on the first line, in front of the function, and to remove the `console.log` part at the end of the code.

```
export const toRna = function(dna) {
  const parseDna = dna.split("");
  let rna = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < parseDna.length; i++) {
    if (parseDna[i] === "G") {
      rna += "C";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "C") {
      rna += "G";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "T") {
      rna += "A";
    } else if (parseDna[i] === "A") {
      rna += "U";
    } else {
      throw new Error("Invalid input DNA.");
    // This part doesn't work for some reason.
    }
  }
  return rna;
};

// console.log(toRna("U"));
```

Comment: For some reason, when I added export to the code, it caused an error in node. Is that normal?

Comment: That isn't the expected behaviour, as export should actually send the function to the test case. Can you please paste the error's stack trace here and let me know if you maybe made any additional edits to the main code and/or test case? Thank you.